# how to remove two white spaces and first and last white spaces in php

Tags: php, php-5.3

```
$s = "  xyxz  ";
echo trim($s, " "); //out put:xyz
$ss = " xyz  pqrs" ;


echo trim($ss, " "); //out put:xyz  pqrs 
// i want out put:xyz pqrs
```

Hi Friends I got recently `trim($search_string, " ");` function .it is removing last and first word spaces but word middle end user given two spaces or more spaces how to remove those spaces we will put in to single space in php .please help me friends .

sorry for the my bad english

Comment: can you provide an example? and please try to test something before asking!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<?php
$str="Hello World";
echo str_replace(" ","",$str);//HelloWorld
```

**EDIT :**

Deploy a **`Regular Expression`** then

```
<?php
$str="   Hello      World I am  testing this          example   ";//Hello World I am testing this example
echo preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
?>
```

Comment: hello bass i want only remove the double or more white spaces in to single white space.do you understanding what i am trying to say

Answer (score 0):

you can use str_replace to remove all empty space from a string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

str_replace("  ", " ", "string"); // this will replace two spaces with one space.

Answer (score 0):

use preg_replace():

```
  $string = 'First     Last';
  $string = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $string);
  echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` to replace multiple spaces with one.

```
$string = preg_replace("/ {2,}/", " ", $string)
```

If you want to replace any whitespaces in groups of more than two use

```
$string = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", " ", $string)
```

Or, if you want to also replace any whitespaces other than spaces with spaces you can use

```
$string = preg_replace("/(\s+| {2,})/", " ", $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = 'foo   o';
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
// This will be 'foo o' now
echo $str;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `preg_replace("/\s{2,}/"," ",$string)`

Answer (score 0):

trim + str_replace

```
echo trim(str_replace("  ", " ", $ss));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode and implode to remove multiple whitespaces from middle as well as first and last spaces.

Use following function to simple return trimmed string.

```
function removeSpaces( $string )
{
    // split string by space into array
    string_in_array = explode(" ", $string_filter );

    // concatenate array into string excluding empty array as well as spaces
    $string_with_only_one_space = implode(' ', array_filter( $string_in_array ));

    return $string_with_only_one_space;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ltrim` and `rtrim` function, for example

```
$text = ' kompetisi indonesia ';
echo $text.'<br/>';
$text = ltrim(rtrim($text));
echo $text;
```

result
 kompetisi indonesia
kompetisi indonesia

reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php